# Common sorting funcion for getting ngTableParams is not working for non-Grouping Table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, grouping, ngtable

I have created an application in `angularJS` with `ngTable`, The application is having two tables, one table is using grouping functionality with sorting and another one as normal table without grouping and need only sorting, The application is working fine but sorting is not working for the table which is not having grouping functionality.

Since i am using two tables and both uses sorting feature i made a common method for getting the `ngTableParams` object like as shown below, but unfortunately sorting is not working for the first table which does not having grouping, for second table with grouping feature sorting is working.

**[Working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/lSl6uXPKHfuPSgI0rEGX?p=preview)**

```
// NOT WORKING
$scope.tableParamsOne = getNgTableParams('name', 'desc' ,'', $scope.myDataOne); 

// WORKING
$scope.tableParamsTwo = getNgTableParams('name', 'desc' ,'name', $scope.myDataTwo); 


function getNgTableParams(sortingField, sortingOrder, groupByField, tableDatas) 
{
  return new ngTableParams({
           sorting: {
               sortingField: sortingOrder
           }
       }, {
           groupBy: groupByField,
           getData: function($defer, params) {
               var orderedData = $filter('orderBy')(tableDatas, params.orderBy());
               $defer.resolve(orderedData);
           }
       });
}
```

can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Comment: your question's formatting is great,but you should do more research before post the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in first table you need  iterate over `$data`

```
<table ng-table="tableParamsOne" class="table">
    <tr ng-hide="false" ng-repeat="user in $data">
      <td sortable="name" data-title="'Name'">
        {{user.name}}
      </td>
      <td sortable="age" data-title="'Age'">
        {{user.age}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/SRX9rgXe8PkaMiMvijyJ?p=preview)